# MYSQL Indexes for performance and scalalbility

Tags: mysql, indexing

Ive been using PHP and MySQL for a while now and I still don't understand when I should add Indexes to colums in my MySQL tables to increase performance. Are there any simple resources to help explain this to me?

Comment: [http://www.howtoforge.com/when-to-use-indexes-in-mysql-databases](http://www.howtoforge.com/when-to-use-indexes-in-mysql-databases)

Answer (score 0):

In short, anything that will appear in a `WHERE` or `ON` clause should probably have an index on it.  As well, you can use MySQL's `EXPLAIN` command to see how it actually executes the query which can point out where indexes are needed.